# ERROR: PleskFatalException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): Connection refused (auth.php:142)

Tags: linux, vps

Today when I'm trying access to my VPS the plesk give me this error message

```
ERROR: PleskFatalException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): Connection refused (auth.php:142)
```

The message appears when I open the URL for plask's admin panel.

Last week when I accessed was working perfectly

The OS is Parallels Plesk 11.5.30, I think its linux based

I didn't tried anything because I have no idea what I can do, I'm not a linux guy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact your VPS provider and send them the error message.  Their Plesk installation is broken.